# SQL script change file on explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been looking all over the place and maybe it's not possible for a reason.
I'm trying to perform a full renaming of SQL database through a sql script
(end to end changes with mdf & ldf files. Both in sql server and in explorer).

Found many information about how to change (best one is [here](https://sqlandme.com/tag/change-logical-file-names/)),
but non with changing the "explorer name".

Is it possible via sql script?

Thanks,
Naor.

### Update for clarification

I'm not interested on the name in sql server object explorer.
I'm talking about the file name itself in windows file system. (in ..\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio will not automatically update the names of objects in the Object Explorer, you must click the Refresh button/menu-item manually. There is no way to get around this.

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve _Step 2: Rename Physical files_, from your link in T-SQL? If it is enabled you can use `xp_cmdshell`